# VBA - Add Class as Item in ComboBox

Tags: vba, collections, combobox

I have a text file containing CSV information.
I want a single field from each entry to populate a combobox.
But I want to preserve the relationship with the other data when the user picks an item from the combobox.

For example:

```
Dim c as Collection

c = ReadFile() 'returns a Collection of variant arrays to c

Dim info As Variant

For Each info In c
    'Let's say, for example, info(3) contains the human-friendly name of the item
    '(which may or may not be unique)
    'and info(0) contains the unique ID of the item (which I need to reference later)

    'I'd like to put:
    'combobox.AddItem(info)
    'but I'm getting errors unless I do something more specific, like:

    combobox.AddItem (info(3))

    'Can I preserve each info() object as a part of the combobox?
    'I know this can be done in .NET but I'm not so sure about VBA.

Next info
```

Is it possible to store my collection of "info" in a combobox?

Later in the code I'd like the convenience of using something like:

```
combobox.SelectedItem(0)
```

or

```
combobox.Value(0)
```

to retrieve my unique ID.

Comment: `AddItem` expects a string as the `Item` value. It doesn't accept an object as in (eg) .NET  You'd have to keep the other information in a Global variable (or Local Static variable)

Comment: So there's no collection of objects associated with a combobox at all? I'll accept that as an answer if you want to post it instead of a comment :)

Comment: Are you in Excel, Access, or some other Office application?  I'd suggest storing the arrays into a Scripting.Dictionary, displaying the "human readable" name for the user to select and with the "ID" you get from the combobox, looking it up in the Dictionary.  However, the method would be slightly different depending upon the application you are in.

Comment: Solidworks VBA. I am using dictionaries for other things in this project but the problem becomes: If I try to use the readable name for the dictionary key I could possibly have duplicate keys.

Comment: If you're adding the "human readable" names in the same order as they exist in the array, you can always use the index of the selected item in the combobox as an index into the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have SolidWorks, so I can't test this in that context, but here's an example built in Excel. I'm betting that the Combobox class is similar enough.

```
Option Explicit
Dim colTemp As Collection

Public Sub Populate_Combobox()
    Dim arrThings() As Variant
    Dim varItem As Variant

    'This section constructs a data structure like you describe: a Collection of Variant Arrays
    Set colTemp = New Collection
    arrThings = Array(123, "fhdg", "Umbrella")
    colTemp.Add arrThings
    arrThings = Array(156, "afibewsrbeld", "Car")
    colTemp.Add arrThings
    arrThings = Array(34, "afifelbxcfbd", "Car")
    colTemp.Add arrThings
    arrThings = Array(247, "afisbdfheldd", "Shoe")
    colTemp.Add arrThings

    For Each varItem In colTemp
        'This adds the "human readable" name to the dropdown
        ComboBox1.AddItem varItem(2) 
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'This handles the event that a user has changed their selection in the dropdown
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arrThings As Variant

    'The index of the ComboBox selection is used to get the correct array out of the Collection
    arrThings = colTemp.Item(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1)

    'Just to show it's the correct item...
    Dim strOutput As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrThings)
        strOutput = strOutput & " " & arrThings(i)
    Next
    MsgBox "The chosen item contains these: " & strOutput
End Sub
```

EDIT: Fixed an issue where, because I had failed to use Option Explicit, I accidentally created an undeclared variable.  Thankfully it had no effect on the functioning of the code, but it easily could have.  Don't make my mistake - ALWAYS use Option Explicit ;)